# Listen to image load in Add-On SDK

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to **listen to the loading of images** (or stylesheets) via the Mozilla Add-On SDK?

Having the user load a new URL can be found via the [`Page-Mod` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod), AJAX calls via [overriding `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.*()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596583/javascript-detect-an-ajax-event/3597640#3597640).

Yet both only listen to loading of entirely new pages, not to the attached images of a page. Also, the image source might be changed for example in Javascript.

(It might be possible to use a [`http-on-modify-request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests), as pointed to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers), but how can you access the [`nsIHttpChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIHttpChannel)'s URL and  parameters?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to every network request via

```
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var httpRequestObserver = {
    observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
        if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
            var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            var myURL = httpChannel.URI.spec;
            console.log("url: " + myURL);
        }
    },

    register: function() {
        var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
        observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request", false);
    },

    unregister: function() {
        var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
        observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request");
    }
};

httpRequestObserver.register();

exports.onUnload = function(reason) {
    httpRequestObserver.unregister();
};
```

See also [Firefox Addon observer http-on-modify-request not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222873/firefox-addon-observer-http-on-modify-request-not-working-properly).

#### URI access

The `nsIHttpChannel` extends [`nsIChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIChannel), which has a [URI Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIChannel#Attributes) of type [`nsIURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIURI), which has a `spec` attribute that contains the whole URL (including schema, parameters, ref, etc).